# Where does a Centos7 VM get the IP address for the local host name from?

Tags: centos, networking, vmware

On my centos7 VM, `hostname` says `bmargulies-centos7`, `domainname` says `(none)`, `dig bmargulies-centos7` says what's below, and ping of that hostname hangs. Where does the IP address `92.242.140.21` come from?

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3 <<>> bmargulies-centos7
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55643
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:
; MBZ: 0005 , udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bmargulies-centos7.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION: bmargulies-centos7.  5   IN  A   92.242.140.21

;; Query time: 29 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.74.2#53(192.168.74.2)
;; WHEN: Sat May 21 14:04:49 EDT 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 63
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from your provider's internal DNS server at 192.168.74.2.

That DNS server is most likely configured in `/etc/resolv.conf` unless you already have `bind` running on your machine.

Comment: Oh, Verizon! Time to manually configure something else.